# extract rows for which first non-zero element is one

Tags: r

I would like to extract every row from the data frame `my.data` for which the first non-zero element is a `1`.

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '

     x1 x2 x3 x4
      0  0  1  1
      0  0  0  1
      0  2  1  1
      2  1  2  1
      1  1  1  2
      0  0  0  0
      0  1  0  0
', header = TRUE)

my.data

desired.result <- read.table(text = '

     x1 x2 x3 x4
      0  0  1  1
      0  0  0  1
      1  1  1  2
      0  1  0  0
', header = TRUE)

desired.result
```

I am not even sure where to begin.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.  Thank you for any suggestions or advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
# index of rows
idx <- apply(my.data, 1, function(x) any(x) && x[as.logical(x)][1] == 1)

# extract rows
desired.result <- my.data[idx, ]
```

The result:

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  0  0  1  1
2  0  0  0  1
5  1  1  1  2
7  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: Winner, fastest solution according to microbenchmark

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `apply` to iterate over all rows:

   ```
   first.element.is.one <- apply(my.data, 1, function(x) x[x != 0][1] == 1)
   ```

   The function passed to `apply` compares the first `[1]` non-zero `[x != 0]` element of `x` to `== 1`. It will be called once for each row, `x` will be a vector of four in your example.
2. Use `which` to extract the indices of the candidate rows (and remove `NA` values, too):

   ```
   desired.rows <- which(first.element.is.one)
   ```
3. Select the rows of the matrix -- you probably know how to do this.

Bonus question: Where do the `NA` values mentioned in step 2 come from?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best answer, but:

```
rows.to.extract <- apply(my.data, 1, function(x) {
  no.zeroes <- x[x!=0]  # removing 0
  to.return <- no.zeroes[1] == 1     # finding if first number is 0

  # if a row is all 0, then to.return will be NA
  # this fixes that problem
  to.return[is.na(to.return)] <- FALSE # if row is all 0

  to.return
})
my.data[rows.to.extract, ]

  x1 x2 x3 x4
1  0  0  1  1
2  0  0  0  1
5  1  1  1  2
7  0  1  0  0
```